# typescript cannot infer the type coming from a callback function

Tags: typescript

I define a function like this:

```
const func1 = <T, R>(x: T) => (f: (x: T) => R) => f(x)
```

Then call it like this:

```
func1(2 + 4)(a => a > 5)
```

I would expect the type of the result is boolean. but the type of func1 that typescript inferred is:

```
use<number, unknown>(x: number): (f: (x: number) => unknown) => unknown
```

How do I force typescript to recognize the type R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redefine it so `func1()` returns a generic function since you don't know what `R` is until a function is passed in.

```
const func2 = <T>(x: T) => <R>(f: (x: T) => R) => f(x)
```

Comment: got it. this will make R a type variable for the callback function

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to explicitly provide `T` and `R`, like so:

```
func1<number, boolean>(2 + 4)(a => a > 5)
```

Comment: this will not be necessary if we define the function like Jeff does, the types can be automatically inferred by typescript during usage